# Connecting to Docker from external network: modifying YML file

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a Learning Locker server within Docker (on Windows 10, Docker using WSL for emulation) using the repo from [michzimney](https://github.com/michzimny/learninglocker2-docker). This service is composed of several Docker containers (Mongo, Redis, NGINX, etc) networked together. Using the provided `docker-compose.yml` file I have been able to set up the service and access it from localhost, but I cannot access the server from any machine on the rest of my home network.

This is a specific case, but some guidance will be valuable as I am very new to Docker and **will need to build many such environments in the future**, for now in Windows but later in Docker on Synology, **where the services can be access from network and internet**.

My research has led me to [user-defined bridging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290623/docker-access-from-other-machines-on-local-network) using `docker -p [hostip]:80:80` but this didn't work for me. I have also turned off Windows firewall since that seems to cause a host of issues for some but still no effect. I tried to [bridge my virtual switch manager for WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002681/connecting-to-wsl2-server-via-local-network) using Windows 10 Hyper-V manager, but that didn't work, and I have tried [bridging the WSL connector to LAN using basic Windows 10 networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111247/how-to-access-docker-container-from-another-machine-on-local-network) but that didn't work and I had to reset my network.

- So the **first question** is is this a Windows networking issue or a
  Docker configuration issue?
- The **second question**, assuming it's a
  Docker configuration issue, is how can I modify the following YML
  file to make the service accessible to the outside network:

```
version: '2'
services:

   mongo:
       image: mongo:3.4
       restart: unless-stopped
       volumes:
           - "${DATA_LOCATION}/mongo:/data/db"

   redis:
       image: redis:4-alpine
       restart: unless-stopped

   xapi:
       image: learninglocker/xapi-service:2.1.10
       restart: unless-stopped
       environment:
           - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/learninglocker_v2
           - MONGO_DB=learninglocker_v2
           - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
       depends_on:
           - mongo
           - redis
       volumes:
           - "${DATA_LOCATION}/xapi-storage:/usr/src/app/storage"

   api:
       image: michzimny/learninglocker2-app:${DOCKER_TAG}
       environment:
           - DOMAIN_NAME
           - APP_SECRET
           - SMTP_HOST
           - SMTP_PORT
           - SMTP_SECURED
           - SMTP_USER
           - SMTP_PASS
       command: "node api/dist/server"
       restart: unless-stopped
       depends_on:
           - mongo
           - redis
       volumes:
           - "${DATA_LOCATION}/app-storage:/opt/learninglocker/storage"

   ui:
       image: michzimny/learninglocker2-app:${DOCKER_TAG}
       environment:
           - DOMAIN_NAME
           - APP_SECRET
           - SMTP_HOST
           - SMTP_PORT
           - SMTP_SECURED
           - SMTP_USER
           - SMTP_PASS
       command: "./entrypoint-ui.sh"
       restart: unless-stopped
       depends_on:
           - mongo
           - redis
           - api
       volumes:
           - "${DATA_LOCATION}/app-storage:/opt/learninglocker/storage"
           - "${DATA_LOCATION}/ui-logs:/opt/learninglocker/logs"

   worker:
       image: michzimny/learninglocker2-app:${DOCKER_TAG}
       environment:
           - DOMAIN_NAME
           - APP_SECRET
           - SMTP_HOST
           - SMTP_PORT
           - SMTP_SECURED
           - SMTP_USER
           - SMTP_PASS
       command: "node worker/dist/server"
       restart: unless-stopped
       depends_on:
           - mongo
           - redis
       volumes:
           - "${DATA_LOCATION}/app-storage:/opt/learninglocker/storage"

   nginx:
       image: michzimny/learninglocker2-nginx:${DOCKER_TAG}
       environment:
           - DOMAIN_NAME
       restart: unless-stopped
       depends_on:
           - ui
           - xapi
       ports:
           - "443:443"
           - "80:80"
```

So far I have attempted to change the `ports` option to the following:

```
        ports:
            - "192.168.1.102:443:443"
            - "192.168.1.102:80:80"
```

But then the container wasn't even accessible from the host machine anymore. I also tried adding `network-mode=host` under the nginx service but the build failed saying it was not compatible with port mapping. Do I need to set `network-mode=host` for every service or is the problem something else entirely?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of your docker-compose.yml, you are exposing ports 80 & 443 to your host (Windows machine). So, if your windows IP is 192.168.1.102 - you should be able to reach http://192.168.1.102 & https://192.168.1.102 on your LAN if there is nothing blocking it (firewall etc.).

You can confirm that you are indeed listening on those ports by running 'netstat -a' and checking to see if you are LISTENING on those ports.

Comment: Strange on port 80 netstat reports TIME_WAIT but on port 443, with the firewall completely turned off (I had already added a rule for 443) it finally connected! Thank you! I thought I was doing something terribly wrong.